# Javascript history go — if not, go to index.html

Tags: javascript, tumblr

To go back to the appropriate tumblr page, we're using:

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)"> Back </a>
```

However, we're getting a lot of traffic directly from the twitter app, and this stops the function working. Is there a way so that if the history.go doesn't work (or takes you outside the site), it will just take you to index.html?

This is one of the pages the history button is on: http://lexican.info/post/49265445109/sesquipedalophobia

Thanks for any help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I don't think this is possible as there is no relationship between a **post** and what **page** of the index the post is displayed on.

Comment: Would it be possible to send it to the default homepage?

Comment: Yes, if you update the `href="/"` that should return the user to the homepage.

Comment: Sorry, but only if the history.go doesn't work? A if history.go works, go back. If not, go to index?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, as its not something I have done before. A quick search pulls this up (document.referrer) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7651297/2312574

You could try checking if the referrer is from your site, with something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4362869/2312574  

If your site is the referrer, keep the link as `<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)"> Back </a>` else change the link to `<a href="/"> Back </a>`  

Again I am not 100% sure if this will work or what implications incognito mode or opening a link from an app would have on the referrer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check how many page in the history list with **history.length**:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_his_length.asp