# Link from other site should open the first link of the site

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Have a look at the site below, will delete it later:-

[Career page][1]

On this page, if I come from other website like Facebook/ Linked in, it should look like this:-

![Image 1][2]

And If I visit from the same site, it should be like below:-

here is my JS code related to that. Please suggest what to do:-

```
function pageLoad() {
        $("#careerdiv").accordion({              
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false,
            active: false
        });

        $("a#various15").fancybox({
            'width': 720,
            'height': 390,
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'type': 'iframe',
            'speedIn': 600,
            'speedOut': 400,
            'overlayShow': true,
            'overlayOpacity': 0.8,
            'overlayColor': '#000',
            'padding': '0px',
            'onComplete': function () { $('.closer').click(function () { parent.$.fancybox.close(); }) }
        });
    }
```

Please suggest what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please change the following of your code:

```
$("#careerdiv").accordion({              
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    active: false
});
```

with the following (of which host check taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4362869/306921)):

```
if( document.referrer.indexOf(location.protocol + "//" + location.host) === 0){ 
                $("#careerdiv").accordion({              
                    collapsible: true,
                    autoHeight: false,
                    active: false
                });
            } else{
                $("#careerdiv").accordion({              
                    collapsible: true,
                    autoHeight: false,
                    active: 0
                });
            }
```

which checks if the referrer is you **own** host and activates the first accordion which has the index `0` (in zero based index). Remember to test it on the server.

Comment: Yes will surely check from office. Now m at sweet home..take care

Comment: Wooer: I think, I tested the links with 2 conditions. 1) From my site and 2) from the other(Facebook) site and it is working correctly. Let me confirm that with tester.

Comment: Wooer: Are you their ??

Comment: Yes, tester also tested, now giving client to test.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('facebook.com') > -1) {
  // do something for visitors from facebook here
}
```

Comment: where to add this code ?? and how it open as per my first image ?

Comment: Inside your pageLoad() function, probably... as for how you control the accordion to open up automatically, you should look at the documentation for that plugin for that answer. Probably the `active` field, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: can you edit your answer post and let me know so that I can check it on my website whether it is working or not ?

Comment: I don't understand, you want me to read the documentation for the accordion plugin for you? You can find it here: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/ If you don't want to put in any effort to learn, then I don't want to put in any effort to help you.

Comment: @Nadeem there is surely an api function for that as Hamza mentions, of course you could also just call `.click()` on the element that opens the accordion

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.referrer`. Here is a contrived example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var referrer =  document.referrer;
   if(referrer.match(/stackoverflow.com/i)){ // change this to the name of your site
     $('#targetDiv').show(); // change this line as needed for you actual page
   }
   else{     
     $('#targetDiv2').show(); // remove this line for you actual page
     // $('.ui-accordion-header').eq(0).click(); // uncomment this line for your actual page
   }
});
```

```css
.none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="targetDiv" class="none">You see this, so you came from SO</div>
<div id="targetDiv2" class="none">You see this, so you came from a site other than SO</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, And How to open the first `div` of the page if it comes from other website rather than the same website ?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to check if referrer is from fb || li and open accordion number 1 I guess:

```
if( document.referer ){
    $("#careerdiv").accordion({              
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: 1
} else {
    $("#careerdiv").accordion({              
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        active: false
    });     
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want that. but in your both condition is same, I want like first Image if it is `if( document.referrer.indexOf('facebook.com') > -1 || document.referrer.indexOf('linkedin.com') > -1 ){`

Comment: you can change if statement to this `if( document.referer != "" ) ..` and then show `active: 1` is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, but it is opening the accordion if I visit from the same site

Comment: referer is not gonna change if you go to (click on logo) homepage and return to that page.. it is persistent while the session is open.. try to open page in incognito window

Comment: Tried from their, it is still opening if I visit from the same site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76029/discussion-between-oserk-and-nadeem).